# JSX Error on Script Reference

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've spent the last two months programming JavaScript for SharePoint and wanted to move from Notepad ++ to VS Code.  When opening my JavaScript in default install of Code, I'm getting [JSX] and [TS] errors that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

I get these when also creating even a very simple js file.

For example, if I create this file, there are no errors.

```
<script>
     console.log("Hello World");
</script>
```

I get no errors.  But when I place a script reference to JQuery (by hand writing or copy and pasting) to a hosted library, I get the following error:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    console.log("Hello World");
</script> <----Error points to this space.
```

> [ts] JSX expressions must have one parent element.

This points to the space right after the second closing script tag.  This occurs in every one of the files I make and view in VS Code.  It's driving me nuts as I've not been able to find the answer.  Did I miss something in the settings that would help this?

Thanks for any help you can provide.  I love using VS Code much better than Notepad ++ but this is frustrating me to see this error on every file I open.

Comment: It looks like it expects to be parsing a TypeScript file instead of Javascript. I'm not sure if that helps you troubleshoot. I'd say make sure your file is a .js extension and do NOT place script tags in it, or if it's a different file type, like html, then you DO include script tags. What's the file name you're editing and what type does the editor say it thinks it is?

Comment: The files are saved as .js files.  When using these files in SharePoint development, the js code must be enclosed in <script> tags so that when they are included in the page render, they are properly enclosed.